# My Partial View is not showing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Good day, I am currently working on my school project with a multi-step form. this step has a search box wherein when clicked, based on data typed, will call a partial view with a table inside a modal popup enabled by `ajax`.

the modal popup shows but the table is not found. i guess the partial view is not retrieved. what am i doing wrong? tnx.

**My View goes like this:**

**This is the searchbox**

```
  <div class="wizard-step">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Taxpayer Name")
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.taxpayername, new { @class = "form-control", id = "taxpayername" })
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnGet" type="button">Search</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**This is the modal**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Partial View Example</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv">


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is the script

```
<script>
$(function () {
$("#btnGet").click(function () {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Wizard/ShowTaxPayer",
            data: '{name: "' + $("#taxpayername").val() + '" }',
            success: function (response) {
                $("#myModalBodyDiv").html(response);


                $("#myModal").modal("show");


            }

        })
})
});
</script>
```

This is my Controller

```
    public ActionResult ShowTaxPayer(string name)
    {
        List<Payer> listEmp = db.Payers.Where(x => x.name == name).ToList();
        ViewBag.TaxPayer = listEmp;
        return PartialView("_ShowTaxPayer");
    }
```

*My partial view*

```
<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.TaxPayer)
{
    <tr>
        <td><b>Taxpayer ID</b></td>
        <td>@item.objid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td>@item.name</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Address</b></td>
            <td>@item.primaryaddres</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Birthdate</b></td>
            <td>@item.birthdate</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Civil Status</b></td>
            <td>@item.civilstatus</td>
        </tr>
}

</table>
```

Your help will be highly appreciated. tnx

Comment: You are doing a `type:POST` ajax call. Have you added `[HttpPost]` attribute to your `ActionResult`?

Comment: yup. have tried that already but still none. im just wondering, well my other codes worked while this didnt.

Comment: Check if you have any console errors.. Also try placing a debugger in `ActionResult` and see if it gets hit..

Comment: im sorry for the question but how do you those? im sorry because im really new to these things.

Comment: You are using Visual Studio right..?

Comment: yes. if im not mistaken this is 2015.

Comment: Yes.. that's fine.. When you run your application, first of all check your browser console has any errors.. Press F12 and a console will open. In that console you have `Console` tab. Click on that and see if you have any js error

Comment: all i could see is the module is optimized, skipped is enabled and exit thread. didnt see anything somehow related to js.

Comment: Ok.. Can you place debugger in Visual Stuido and Run your application in debug mode and see if breakpoint hits there on search..

Comment: Hi sr. since i cant figure this way, i just created a new code and somehow cheated my ui to look like the one i wanted. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of  http post parameter, try to set [FromBody] in the controller's parameter
for more information please check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api